# Android ViewPagerIndicator doesn`t show tags

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I`m implementing ViewPagerIndicator like adviced here: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537

And everything's alright except that my inddicator doesn't shows tags, that I'm setting. Here`s how I set them:

public class MainPagerActivity extends Activity {

```
private ViewPager pager;
private List<View> pages;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main);
    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.main_pager);
    pages = new ArrayList<View>();

    pager.setCurrentItem(0);     

    ListView all = (ListView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_thoughts, null);
    all.setTag("All thoughts");
    pages.add(all);

    ListView favorites = (ListView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_thoughts, null);
    favorites.setTag(R.string.favorites);
    pages.add(favorites);


    RelativeLayout profile = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, null);
    profile.setTag(R.string.profile);
    pages.add(profile);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(pages);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
    titleIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The title-based indicators of ViewPagerIndicator use whatever is returned from the `getTitle(int)` method of the `PagerAdapter` which backs your `ViewPager` to display titles. Ensure that you are returning non-`null` and non-empty strings for each page.